# Getting error While reading phone number from JSON in Angular.js

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, angularjs, rest

I am newbie to angular.js,  I am developing a registration form, When the user fill the form and submits , getting the error as in the image[image]

I checked the error reference[org.vitti.bean.User] chain shown in error message, but i did not found any error there, in my mysql DataBat also i given my phone number type as BigInt..  But when i giving phone number as 9 digits it is accepting  the form.

Here is mu User.java class

```
@Id
@Column(name="phoneno", nullable=false)
private Long    phoneno;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// GETTER & SETTER FOR THE KEY FIELD
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void setPhoneno( Long phoneno )
{
    this.phoneno = phoneno ;
}
public Long getPhoneno()
{
    return this.phoneno;
}
```

Can anyone Please help me..

Comment: its database related error, you need to increase `phoneno` property size limit on server side

Comment: @pankajparkar thanks for replay. in data base i set phone number type as Bigint(100).

Comment: @Ashokkumar Is it working now ?
And pankaj Bingo :-)

Comment: @Ashokkumar you are right on db side, Change your model class `User` property value `phoneno;
` to `Decimal` instead of long

Comment: @squiroid Thanks for replay,  it is showing same error as i shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Your Long is not working because all literal numbers in java are by default ints, which has range -2147483648 to  2147483647 inclusive.

So 
`Long phone=999999999`9 is not valid it must be like 9999999999L(L at suffix)

Instead I prefer to store phone number in string and while

`String phone="9999999999"` but while storing it into database i parsed it into Long

Long.parseLong(phone).

Comment: i will check and inform. Thanks for replay

Comment: sorry for delay, i converted the user entered details into json object like this {"phonenumber":999999999,"firstname":"user","lastname":"mak"}